# PHP - Can't list files from an FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I have an FTP account I'm trying to list files from but I can't get it to work

FileZilla is able to list them, but only when strictly setting it to active mode rather than passive

Example output from FileZilla

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
Command:    PORT 192,168,68,115,213,202
Response:   200 PORT command successful
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Opening connection
Response:   226 Transfer complete
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

In my PHP code I've tried the following

```
$connection = ftp_connect($host, 21);
    
ftp_login($connection, $username, $password);

var_dump(ftp_size($connection, 'tarbert.jpg'));
var_dump(ftp_mlsd($connection, '.'));
var_dump(ftp_rawlist($connection, '.'));
var_dump(ftp_nlist($connection, '.'));
```

Which outputs

```
int(227978)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

As you can see by the call to `ftp_size`, there are files there and it can see them, but the calls to list the files all return false

I've tried the usual answer of setting to passive mode but that just makes it timeout

Does anyone have any suggestions on what else I could try?

**Mini update**

Strangely, if I move the ftp_size call to be after the others then that also returns false so it seems like the initial call to list files breaks something

I've tried moving each of the 3 list functions to be the first call but this makes no difference to the outcome

**Update with FileZilla full log**

```
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220-Welcome To Rumpus!
Response:   220 Service ready for new user
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   530 USER and PASS required first
Command:    AUTH SSL
Response:   530 USER and PASS required first
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Command:    USER my_user
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   230 User logged in
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 MACOS Server
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Extensions supported:
Response:    SIZE
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    APPE
Response:    MDTM
Response:    MACB
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    PROT
Response:    EPSV
Response:    MLSD
Response:    UTF8
Response:   211 End
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   220 UTF8 OPTS ON
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I (Image)
Command:    PORT 192,168,68,115,204,128
Response:   200 PORT command successful
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Opening connection
Response:   226 Transfer complete
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

**Update with curl log**

```
curl -v --list-only ftp://XX.XX.XX.XX --user "username:password"
*   Trying XX.XX.XX.XX:21...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to XX.XX.XX.XX (XX.XX.XX.XX) port 21 (#0)
< 220-Welcome To Rumpus!
< 220 Service ready for new user
> USER username
< 331 Password required
> PASS password
< 230 User logged in
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
* Request has same path as previous transfer
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||3004|)
*   Trying XX.XX.XX.XX:3004...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connecting to XX.XX.XX.XX (XX.XX.XX.XX) port 3004
* Connected to XX.XX.XX.XX (XX.XX.XX.XX) port 21 (#0)
> TYPE A
< 200 Type set to A (ASCII)
> NLST
< 150 Opening connection
* Maxdownload = -1
# FILE LIST HERE
* Remembering we are in dir ""
< 226 Transfer complete
* Connection #0 to host XX.XX.XX.XX left intact
```

Comment: try `ftp_pasv($connection, <both true|false>);`

Comment: As mentioned in the original question, I have tried this. Enabling passive makes it timeout, disabling it makes no difference as that's the default

Comment: Check your PHP error logs, or enable display_errors - a false return value will usually be accompanied by a Warning explaining what failed.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl updated with full output for connection

Comment: `$host` is different

Comment: No, PHP is running on a server so a different IP

Comment: It works fine via `curl --list-only ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx --user "user:pass"`, there's nothing else installed on the server to test with other than curl

Answer (score -1):

Just in case anyone else stumbles on this, it appears the FTP is behind a NAT

See this link for details

http://www.elitehosts.com/blog/php-ftp-passive-ftp-server-behind-nat-nightmare/

I couldn't find a fix as this particular FTP doesn't allow passive connections but if yours does then that link will help

Comment: @MartinPrikryl updated the original question with the curl output

Comment: What is you add `--disable-epsv` to `curl` commandline?

Comment: It fails. `Connect data stream passively` -> `ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0` -> `Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: Can you post log of that?